# Use Proxy and Headers in AngleSharp.Io

Tags: http, anglesharp

I am trying to get AngleSharp to use both a proxy and set header properties like this:

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyMan.GetProxy()),
            UseProxy = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };
        var requester = new DefaultHttpRequester();
        requester.Headers["User-Agent"] = Tools.GetAgentString();
        requester.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US";
        requester.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1";
        requester.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        var config = Configuration.Default
            .WithRequesters(handler)
            .With(requester)
            .WithTemporaryCookies()
            .WithDefaultLoader();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var doc = await context.OpenAsync(Url);
```

When I added the Header requester, it stopped the proxy handler from working.  I know there is some conflict between the .WithRequesters() and the .With() but I cannot locate the proper syntax for doing both in the same request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I am not sure why you use both.

1. The `DefaultHttpRequester` is the requester from AngleSharp and uses `WebClient` underneath
2. `WithRequesters` comes from AngleSharp.Io and adds all available requesters (incl. `HttpClientRequester`)
3. `WithDefaultLoader` puts a loader into the config and registers the default HTTP requester, if no other requester has been registered yet

I think what you want to do should be actually done using the `HttpClientRequester` directly.

```cs
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyMan.GetProxy()),
            UseProxy = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            UseCookies = false,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Append("User-Agent", Tools.GetAgentString());
        // ... and the others if you want, even though `content-type` etc. should / will be determined by AngleSharp
        var config = Configuration.Default
            .With(new HttpClientRequester(client))
            .WithTemporaryCookies()
            .WithDefaultLoader();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var doc = await context.OpenAsync(Url);
```

Comment: Thanks, Florian.  This was helpful but there is one more piece that was working and now isn't.  Not sure what changed.  I need to add these two lines to my request:
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

This should handle the page being returned compressed, but while it works in my older code still, it does not seem to be working in this method.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is because the SPM was used by the `WebRequest`, which is the .NET API used by `DefaultHttpRequester`. `HttpClientRequester` uses `HttpClient` instead - so you'll need to tell the `HttpClient` to accept that certificate.